# Creating multiple Excel Sheets using node-excel-export in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I want to make a report with multiple sheets using [Node-Excel-Export](https://github.com/andreyan-andreev/node-excel-export), Node JS. How do i make it ? I didn't found guide about that. Has anyone here ever made multiple sheets using that library? or does anyone have a library recommendation ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this lib [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)

and you can use workbook to add multiple sheet in the same workbook

Check this docs [WorkBook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#create-a-workbook)

Comment: thanks, I just found another solution